# Javascript redoing html after getting response from Rails Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want my Index to change according to Price descending and Price ascending just like Amazon.

Right now, I send an ajax request to the site, with the new value of the select requesting the data. The site gets the data from database and sorts it.

How can my javascript redraw the cards in my index page with the sorted book response?

BookController.rb

```
def index
  if params.dig("book", "title").nil? && params.dig("users", "university").nil?
    @books = Book.where({title: params.dig("book", "title")})
    .joins(:user).where(users: {university: params.dig("users", "university")})
  elsif !params.dig("book", "title").nil? && params.dig("users", "university").nil?
    @books = Book.where({title: params.dig("book", "title")})
  elsif params.dig("book", "title").nil? && !params.dig("users", "university").nil?
    @books = Book.joins(:user).where(users: {university: params.dig("users", "university")})
  else
    @books = Book.all
  end
  case params[:sort]
    when "Price Descending"
      @books.order(price_cents: "DESC")
    when "Price Ascending"
      @books.order(price_cents: "ASC")
    else
      @books.sort_by(&:created_at)
  end
end
```

Book Index.html.erb

```
<select id="priceSelect">
  <option value="Best Results" selected="selected">Best Results</option>
  <option value="Price Descending">Price Descending</option>
  <option value="Price Ascending">Price Ascending</option>
</select>

.
.
.

<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <div class="col-xs-12 selectable-card">
    <%= link_to book_path(book.id) do %>
      ...   
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<script>
  $('#priceSelect').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "books",
      type: "GET",
      data: {sort: $('#priceSelect :selected').val()},
      success:function(result){
        console.log(result);
      },
    })
  });
</script>
```

And lastly my routes.rb

```
resources :books do
  resources :users
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer may have syntax errors or other issues as I have written it here, without testing. It's just a guide on how to do it. Take these ideas and correct any possible problem.

In your controller you could return a json object:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @books }
end
```

In your html, add a div to mark to area to replace:

```
<div class ="books-info">
  <% @books.each do |book| %>
    <div class="col-xs-12 selectable-card">
      <%= link_to book_path(book.id) do %>
        ...   
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

In your javascript you should process the json response and build the html to replace the original list:

```
<script>
  $('#priceSelect').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "books",
      type: "GET",
      data: {sort: $('#priceSelect :selected').val()},
      success:function(ret){
        // new code;
        var books = JSON.parse(ret); // Not sure if necessary or you can use 'ret'            
        var length = books.length;
        var html = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          html += "<div class='col-xs-12 selectable-card'>";
          html += "<a href='" + books[i].id + "'>" + books[i].name + "</a>";
          html += "</div>";
        }
        $('.books-info').innerHTML = html
      },
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Do I write the respond_to do |format| ... at the bottom of my index books controller or where do I have to put this code in?

Comment: Yes. At the bottom.

Comment: Your ret is my result. Somehow, if I console.log(ret), it gives me the whole html. Using var books = JSON.parse(ret) gives me an Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. So i tried using var books = ret, but using this doesn't change anything. There are no errors using this method though

Comment: Maybe you must add dataType = "json" to the Ajax request.